# I have this kind of problem in java with Solar

Tags: java, gwt, solr

Solr fails with following error:

```
<title>Error 500 {metadata={error-class=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException,root-error-class=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException},msg=SolrCore &apos;certificateCore&apos; is not available due to init failure: Could not load conf for core certificateCore: Can&apos;t load schema /opt/solr/server/solr/certificateCore/conf/schema.xml: copyField source :&apos;CREATED_BY_NAME&apos; is not a glob and doesn&apos;t match any explicit field or dynamicField.,trace=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: SolrCore &apos;certificateCore&apos; is not available due to init failure: Could not load conf for core certificateCore: Can&apos;t load schema /opt/solr/server/solr/certificateCore/conf/schema.xml: copyField source :&apos;CREATED_BY_NAME&apos; is not a glob and doesn&apos;t match any explicit field or dynamicField.
```

Comment: Error seems to say you messed up your conf file. Given that you didn't paste it, no further answer seems possible here. vote-to-close.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `copyField` rule that specifices `CREATED_BY_NAME` as the source column, but this column name does not match any defined field in your schema - thus, it isn't a valid `copyField` instruction.

Remove the `copyField` instruction that references `CREATED_BY_NAME` as its source (or change it to the correct field (or define the field) if it matches a requirement).